# How to preload associations in one-to-many association?

Tags: elixir, ecto

I have the following structure:

`Order` has many `Products`

`Product` has one `Template`

`Order` has many `Templates` through `Products`.

My queries look like:

```
def with_template(query \\ Product) do
  from q in query, preload: :template
end

def with_products(query \\ Order) do
  from q in query, preload: :products
end
```

and when I do:

```
OrderQuery.with_products |> ProductQuery.with_products |> Repo.all
```

I get an error, because of course

```
Order does not have association :template
```

I need to preload `:templates` instead. Is there any way to not write an additional query?

I want to avoid:

```
  from q in Order, preload: [products: :template]
```

But combine and use already defined queries.

Comment: You can't because the preloads is always based on the source given to `from`. Maybe there is a neat way to compose those in the future, but not currently. :)

Comment: you mention "Order has many Templates through Order.", did you mean "Order has many Templates through Product"?

Comment: @shankardevy that's right. Thanks, fixed.